How to run a main class in gradle task in android multi-module project?
In my android multi-module project, I want to execute a Kotlin file to generare code.
My need is:
I have a multi-module project with one app module and lots of library modules.
There is a module named offlinedb. In that I have a main function file in it's  package com.framework.offlinedb.generator. It's a simple main function that just calls a code gen kotlin class.
For that I used a gradle task. But the gradle task unable identify the main sourceset. I tried setting sourcesets etc.
gradle task:
tasks.register<JavaExec>("runCodeGenerator") {
    group = "code generation"
    description = "Runs the code generator in the offlinedb module"

    // Set the classpath to include the compiled classes of the offlinedb module
    classpath = project(":offlinedb").sourceSets["main"].runtimeClasspath
    // Set the main class to be executed
    mainClass.set("com.framework.offlinedb.generator.MainKt")

    // Pass any arguments if needed
    args = listOf("arg1", "arg2") // Replace with actual arguments if any
}

When i try to run the task I got this error:
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':offlinedb'.
> Could not create task ':offlinedb:runCodeGenerator'.
   > SourceSet with name 'main' not found.

When I try to list all sourceset, it returns empty  list like no sourcesets at all.
How to fix this issue. Why I can't find the "main" source set?.
I tried giving android.sourcesets["main"], but I get "unable to locate the main class"
Please help me

Use project(":offlinedb").kotlin.sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath in class path and update kotlin file name with .kt extension. Then it will work

@BobSmith could you please explain more?

Change these two lines
classpath = project(":offlinedb").sourceSets["main"].runtimeClasspath
mainClass.set("com.framework.offlinedb.generator.MainKt")

@BobSmith I got this error "Unresolved reference: runtimeClasspath" after changing like this.
classpath = project(":offlinedb").kotlin.sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath

JVM project
You can access the classpath of the other project like this if it is a Kotlin JVM project:
classpath = files(
    project(":offlinedb")
        .the<KotlinJvmProjectExtension>()
        .target
        .compilations
        .named("main")
        .map { it.output.allOutputs + it.runtimeDependencyFiles }
)

Edit: Android project
If your other project is an Android project (as I now see is the case), you can do this:
classpath = files(
    project(":offlinedb")
        .the<KotlinAndroidProjectExtension>()
        .target
        .compilations
        .named("debug") // Or whatever the build variant name is
        .map { it.output.allOutputs + it.runtimeDependencyFiles }
)

In testing this solution, I had to add a Java toolchain to the Android project to make it work, as there was a Java bytecode compatibility issue. In my case I used:
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
    }
}

Best practice
It's worth being aware, though, that these are not best practice. Ideally you only want to depend on other projects' outputs to keep relationships clear and manageable. More discussion of this is in the documentation.

I got this issue    > Extension of type 'KotlinJvmProjectExtension' does not exist. Currently registered extension types: [ExtraPropertiesExtension, BasePluginExtension, DefaultArtifactPublicationSet, SourceSetContainer, ReportingExtension, JavaToolchainService, JavaPluginExtension, LibraryExtension, LibraryAndroidComponentsExtension, NamedDomainObjectContainer<BaseVariantOutput>, KotlinAndroidProjectExtension, KotlinTestsRegistry, KaptExtension]

Ok I see now you are trying to use an Android project. See edit

Did that. Now getting KotlinJvmAndroidCompilation with name 'main' not found. error

I would expect the name you need to be debug, as noted in the answer, or whatever the build variant name is if you are using flavors, eg demoDebug. If you want to see available compilations, write afterEvaluate { kotlin.target.compilations.forEach { println(it.name } } in the Android project to print their names to stdout when running a build

Correction for typo: afterEvaluate { kotlin.target.compilations.forEach { println(it.name) } }

Great. Your ".named("debug") " updated code works as expected. Thanks . You fixed my 1 week struggle

Catch the bounty !!!

Nice :) well done. I would've answered it when it was new but I've not been as active recently. The bounty meant that I saw the question :)

Shouldn't it be JDK 17 for Android? https://developer.android.com/build/jdks#toolchain

All that link suggests is you might have problems if you use a version before 17. 21, which is almost 9 months old, seems like the most natural choice to me, all things being equal

Move the code into directory buildSrc and convert it into a plugin:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html
Then you can apply that plugin to any code module, where it is required.
A common code module shouldn't contain any plugin code ...
and "code generator" implies, that none of this will be packaged.

Thanks. This also works. But my need to execute something inside a library module itself as per PMs requirement. So the Simon Jacob answer suits for me.

Well, it's nevertheless best practice to keep project & plugin code strictly separated, also useful for reusability (one can package them and then doesn't have to depend on the local buildSrc). Plugins can also dynamically register tasks and therefore do not really care about module names.
